# Remove elements from array using spread

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array of animals `arr = ['cat','dog','elephant','lion','tiger','mouse']`

I want to write a function `remove(['dog','lion'])` which can remove the elements from arr, can we write this function using es6 spread?

example:

```
arr = ['cat','dog','elephant','lion','tiger','mouse']
remove(['cat', 'lion'])
```

arr should get changed to

```
arr = ['dog','elephant','tiger','mouse']
```

Note: I don't want mutations, so please don't suggest solutions that mutates array.

Comment: please add an example, what you mean ...

Comment: filter is no mutation, it returns a new array.

Comment: This question and it's initial requirements is like demanding instructions for nailing a hammer with hacksaw.

Comment: `function remove(x, y) { return x.length == 0 ? x : y.includes(x[0]) ? remove(x.slice(1), y) : [x[0], ...remove(x.slice(1), y)]; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't, because they're not next to each other. There's been some discussion of taking spread and rest syntax further, but even in those discussions, I don't think a series of discontiguous selections would be possible.

I think the closest you can get is to call out the first few specifically and then use rest syntax for everything after `'lion'`:

```js
const arr = ['cat','dog','elephant','lion','tiger','mouse'];
const arr2 = [arr[1], arr[2], ...arr.slice(4)];
console.log(arr2);
```

...which I'm sure isn't what you wanted to do. :-)

Comment: *(Sorry, if you see `'cat'` rather than `'dog'` removed above, hit refresh. Misremembered.)*

Comment: yes, this is not what I wanted. But its sad to know this can't be done.

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand you're looking for a function that has its argument defined using the spread syntax.
Here is an example:

```js
var arr = ['cat','dog','elephant','lion','tiger','mouse'];

function remove(...toRemove){
   toRemove.forEach(item => {
      var index = arr.indexOf(item);
      if(index != -1){
          arr.splice(index, 1);
      }
   })
}

remove('dog', 'lion'); // OR remove(...['dog', 'lion']);
console.log(arr);
```

This is actually changing the original array (it mutates it) you've mentioned that you're not looking for mutation but you've also mentioned this **arr should get changed to...**

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand the selected answer was selected since it does not contain solution to the end goal of removing elements from an array

You can't use spread alone to remove, but you can slice and spread:

```
function removeOne(sourceList, value) {
  const index = sourceList.indexOf(value);
  if (index >= 0 && index < sourceList.length) {
    return [
       ...sourceList.slice(0, index),
       ...sourceList.slice(index+1),
    ];
  }
  return sourceList;
}

function remove(sourceList, removeList) {
  let res = [...sourceList]
  removeList.forEach((item) => {
    res = removeOne(res, item);
  })
  return res;
}
```

Comment: The selected answer explained why what the asker wanted to do couldn't happen

Comment: @Meredith LOL, really? we are engineers, we fix what is broken, even if it's the question that's broken. 

Also, I've always found answers that simply point out what's wrong and don't offer/volunteer information to be beyond unhelpful.  A key difference between a good engineer and a bad one is that good engineer should always volunteer information and fill in knowlege gap if the question/problem is not pose with right context.

Lastly the title has the inquirer's intent: `Remove elements from array using spread`. Simply saying no doesn't satisfy the question's intent.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the array.filter method, it will return array with filtered values,

```
var filterMe = ["cat", "dog", "elephant", "lion", "tiger", "mouse"];
var answer = filterMe.filter((item) => item !== "dog")
                     .filter((item) => item !== "lion");
console.log(answer);
```

Comment: item !== "dog" && item !== "lion"

Answer (score 1):

You can use spread if you want to pass lots of strings like `remove('lion', 'dog')`. Otherwise I don't think spread can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You could take an [iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) and exclude the values from iteration with spread operator.

Btw, it is not really advisable.

```js
function remove(array, items) {
    array[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
        for (let value of Object.values(this)) {
            if (!items.includes(value)) {
                yield value;
            }
        }
    };
}

var array = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'lion', 'tiger', 'mouse'];

remove(array, ['dog', 'lion']);
console.log([...array]);
console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the previous filter solution, but using a regular expression. Beneficial if the remove array is large...

```js
let arr = ['cat', 'dog', 'elephant', 'lion', 'tiger', 'mouse'];
const removeArr = ['cat', 'lion'];
const removeRegExp = new RegExp(removeArr.join('|'));
arr = arr.filter(e => !removeRegExp.test(e));
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Typescript, you can also use the [`Omit` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to remove specific keys from you object/ array.

#### Assuming an interface like this

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  description: string; // <--- assuming you want to omit `description` key
  completed: boolean;
  createdAt: number;
}
 
type TodoPreview = Omit<Todo, "description">;
```

the `TodoPreview` type will now expect an object with the other members included but with `decription` *omitted*

##### This will now be correct

```
const todo: TodoPreview = {
  title: "Clean room",
  completed: false,
  createdAt: 1615544252770,
};
```

##### This will ERROR out

```
const todo: TodoPreview = {
  title: "Clean room",
  completed: false,
  description: 'this should not be here' // <--- TS compiler will complain
  createdAt: 1615544252770,
};
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32287762)